# Add custom xml tag in swagger (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, rest, api, swagger

I want to add a custom tag in my swagger documentation, for example a path tag like this.

```
        /// <summary>
        /// A summary
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks> comments </remarks>
        /// <path>/full/url/to/reach/the/page -> nameOfButton -> nameOfAnotherButton</path>
        [HttpPut]
        [Route("route")]
        public ActionResult Method(){...}
```

How can I make this work? Like adding a new row called Path. Currently it doesn't show in the swagger page. 
[image]

Comment: Where do you expect to see this custom info in Swagger UI? Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @Helen Sorry, I added now.

Comment: _Where exactly_ do you want to add that row? As part of the "Example value"? In the operation description? (Your image does not have an operation description, but in [this example](https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/getPetById) the description is "Returns a single pet".) Somewhere else? If possible, edit the image and mark the exact place. The more details, the easier it is for others to understand your use case and to help you.

Comment: Also, do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: @Helen I'm using Swashbuckle, I add a picture, but to be honest it could be anywhere